Computing $\text{Tor}(A,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$
I am trying to compute $\text{Tor}(A,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$, where $A$ is an abelian group. I have the short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{\cdot p} A\rightarrow A/pA \rightarrow 0.$$
(The provided hint was to use the self-multiplication by $p$ map on $A$).
From here I figured the only way to proceed would be to use the long exact sequence (as we aren't doing any resolutions of any sort) and so we get
$$ 0\rightarrow \text{Tor}(A,\mathbb{Z}[1/p]) \rightarrow \text{Tor}(A,\mathbb{Z}[1/p]) \rightarrow \text{Tor}(A/pA,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])\rightarrow$$
$$\rightarrow A\otimes \mathbb{Z}[1/p]\rightarrow A\otimes \mathbb{Z}[1/p] \rightarrow A/pA\otimes \mathbb{Z}[1/p]\rightarrow 0.$$
But then since we can factor out copies of $p$ from $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, the group $A/pA\otimes \mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ should vanish. From here I don't really know the best way to continue.
I believe that the answer should be $0$ as $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ is torsion-free, but the book I'm reading has not established that result yet.

Be careful, what you claim to be an exact sequence is not. You should either replace the last $A$ by $pA$ or add an extra term with $A/pA$.

@ChristopherNicol Ah yeah, of course. I'll see what I can do from there.

I guess by $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ you mean the ring where $p$ is invertible ? If so $Tor(A,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ should have a structure of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$-module (look at the definition with a resolution). And so in your exact sequence the morphism induced by the multiplication by $p$ should become an isomorphism. So it seems that $Tor(A[p],\mathbb{Z}[1/p])=Tor(A/pA,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])=0$ . It is not the conclusion but it may help.

@Vasting What kind of properties of $\operatorname{Tor}$ do you have access to, aside from the fact that it produces long exact sequences ? For instance, if you know more specifically that $\operatorname{Tor}(-,\Bbb Z[1/p])$ is the left-derived functor of $\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Z[1/p]$, then the result simply comes from the fact that this functor is exact. But I am assuming this is not the approach here, since there's no mention of multiplication by $p$.

@FançoisGatine I'm trying to see if I can get the answer using the hint; I don't really want to use that $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ is flat.

@Vasting how did you get that $\operatorname{Tor}_2(A/pA,\mathbb Z[1/p])=0$?
